# How to validate hidden field using jquery validate?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How to validate input fields that are hidden specifically textarea?

I am using jQuery validate plugin to validate CKEDITOR, but CKEDITOR makes the textarea to

```
display:none;
visibility: hidden;
```

jQuery validate just ignores hidden fields

FYI: CKEDITOR is a WYSWYG editor which replace the textarea field when it runs then updates the textarea with its contents when you save.

Comment: What do you mean "a hidden textarea"? A textarea with display:none or an input field of type hidden?

Comment: You need to provide some HTML and more specifics of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to validate a hidden field?

Comment: @gjohn if you've used CKEDITOR before you will know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've manage to make a workaround on this by setting the

```
width: 0;
height: 0;
position: absolute;
```

of the textarea making it invisible even when there is a value.

Comment: fantastic idea! very interesting and innovating ...!